# TYPO3, old session is loaded when logged in

Tags: php, session, typo3

Wenn browsing through my site while logged in the frontend, TYPO3 sometimes loads an old state of the session. When I'am logged out everything is fine and all session-related things are storred and loaded correctly. I searched for six hours now and i can't really see anymore. I guess I'll start to post the controller which handles the sessions: http://pastebin.com/Guzud1AT

If you need any other information please just ask. The page is live here: http://tinyurl.com/boakjw7

To make it clear: This happens WHILE I'am logged in. Not on log-in and then log-out.

Comment: If you close the browser (all sessions) and reload it, then the session is there as well?? If you there is only one reason left: Permanent Cookies. Check your settings there.

Comment: No, the system is configured that when you close the browser all sessions are deleted: [FE][lifetime] = 0

Comment: And when you close and reopen the browser you are sure there are no cookies left? In firefox and chrome you can easy check this. If no cookies left and you still get "old session" then you system won't create correct new sessions. In this case,fire and forget your installation :) I am not familiar with typo, but there is a general setup problem for sure as typo normally don't have this problem.

Comment: Yes, when i close and reopen the browser i get a new PHPSESSID and fe_typo_user ID. But, look, try to put something in the basket without beeing logged in. Everything works fine. You can add it into the basket and purchase it without trouble. But if you are registered and logged in you can't put something in the basket either purchase something cause sometimes TYPO3 does not load the updated session data.

Comment: As I said, I don't know type for special, but your problem looks like the system is mixing sessions, which is strange. Another problem could be a security tokenizer in each page which don't work correctly. Maybe you can try check for such a functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the input but the answer is a Core-Bug in TYPO3 4.5.23 (and only this version). The Bug has been reported 11 days ago here: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/45570

To fix the session handling problem just install this patch: https://review.typo3.org/#/c/18464/ or downgrade to 4.5.22

Answer (score 0):

I think most probably it's related to typo3 caching. From your comments I think you are mainly focused on "add to basket" feature. The typo3 extension that you have used for this feature should not be cached. The caching of extension section can be avoided by adding it using **COA_INT** or **USER_INT** typo3 cObjects (typoscript). Another option is to avoid extension caching by modifying the extension php code.

Reference links:

http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/current/

http://www.pi-phi.de/164.html

Comment: what happens when you clear cache and reload the page? is that working?